# Google maps paths

Tags: android, path

I want to set paths on a Google maps. I’ve done some coding and able to draw single paths on a Google map. I want to know if there is any method to accomplish my objective. How can I do this?

want to show multiple paths between two Geo coordinators.

I’m new to this and can you please help me to do this. Thank you.

Comment: i cant get your mean.. can you explain?

Comment: i want to show several links i mean routes between two points on a Google maps.say point A and point B is there, i want to link that A and B points.it is a road map. that point A and point B can have several connections(I mean several streets to connect or several roads). From that i want to show those different paths in a single Google map.

Comment: I am developing this by using Android.I've used KML file and already drew a single path like in this image.(http://www.google.lk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.seobythesea.com/wp-images/google-maps-features-14.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.seobythesea.com/2010/10/touring-google-maps/&h=324&w=407&sz=45&tbnid=1YFqmnATlPta8M:&tbnh=91&tbnw=114&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dgoogle%2Bmap%2Bimage%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=google+map+image&usg=__t2-Vt1DC0BsAOCEHG6eBsNehSpY=&docid=QybMv3SER569gM&sa=X&ei=2Rr9T4SULs-qrAf_zpTdBg&ved=0CF4Q9QEwCA&dur=1) i want to link that two points with several different connections.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + (srcLocation.getLatitude())+","+(srcLocation.getLongitude())+"&daddr="+destLat+","+destLon;

Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));

intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
```

Draw route using this. This is for one route.